# Is $\alpha: v \to iv$ normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products, orthonormal

Let n be a positive integer and let $\alpha$ be the endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^n$ defined by $\alpha: v \to iv$. Is $\alpha$ normal?

I guess, yes. I just want to make sure that I've made a valid argument.

Let $v,\:w\in \mathbb{C}^n$. Hence $\langle \alpha(v),w\rangle=\langle iv,w\rangle =\langle v,-iw\rangle  $ which implies that $\alpha^*(v)=-iv$ for all $v\in V.$

Thus, $\alpha^*\alpha(v)=-i(iv)=v=\alpha\alpha^*(v)$ and this means $\alpha$ is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inner product is linear in the second variable:
$$
\langle \alpha(v),w\rangle=
\langle iv,w\rangle=
-i\langle v,w\rangle
=\langle v,-iw\rangle
$$
so indeed $\alpha^*(w)=-iw$. (Similarly if you use the convention that the inner product is linear in the first variable.)

Hence
$$
\alpha^*(\alpha(v))=-i^2v=v,\qquad
\alpha(\alpha^*(v))=-i^2v=v
$$
Good job.